# ImportError when trying to use Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-settings

apologies if this question has been asked a ton, I'm sure it has, and I've been trying for days to figure this out, but I can't wrap my head around it. I've been developing in Python for over 1.5 years, so I'm not a complete beginner.

I can't get Django to work in my command prompt. An example is, when I try to use `py .\manage.py makemigrations` this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\manage.py", line 11, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ".\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
    File ".\manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
    ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Now, I can see what the error says. The thing is my virtual environment is activated and it has Django installed, as seen [here](https://prnt.sc/10zyw07). Moreover, even if I executed outside my venv, it still doesn't work, even though I have all necessary Python directories in my PATH, as seen [here](https://prnt.sc/10zyyi3).

I have verified that `django-admin` is installed on both my venv and my system, as well as Django itself, since I can import it on my Python Console. The version is `3.1.7`. I have also tried reinstalling Django and it didn't work.

Another error I get, when I attempt to run Django console through PyCharm is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I hope this helps you come up with any idea. Could anyone please share any insight on why I'm getting this? I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit: I have installed Django through PIP:

`py -m pip install django`
`py -m pip install djangorestframework`
`py -m pip install django-admin`

Also, Django is imported correctly from the Python Console within the venv:

```
>>> import django
>>> django
<module 'django' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py'>
```

Answer (score 0):

in cmd to create a virtualenv

```
python -m venv virtualenv_name
```

to enable virtualenv

```
virtualenv_name\scripts\activate.bat
```

then

```
pip install django
```

and to create a project

```
django-admin startproject  projectname
```

to run the project

```
cd projectname

python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Καλησπέρα, this is the error I get: `OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'`

Comment: Καλησπερα ,  maybe something is wrong with  the python installation  or the virtualenv